# How to save a cookie before ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I have ajax request in index.php

```
function callMe() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "funkcija.php",
        data: "id=1",
        success: function(response){
            $("#badge").html(response);
        }
    });
}


callMe();
setInterval(callMe, 30000); // every 30 sec
```

It is calling funkcija .php every 30 sec. In funkcija.php I am trying to save cookie like this and re retore it later

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).unload(function() {
        //save scroll on unload
        $.cookie('scroll_x_<?php echo $offerid ?>',$('.funkcija3-<?php echo $offerid ?>').scrollLeft());
        $.cookie('scroll_y_<?php echo $offerid ?>',$('.funkcija3-<?php echo $offerid ?>').scrollTop());
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //restore scroll when the dom is ready
        var x = $.cookie('scroll_x_<?php echo $offerid ?>');
        var y = $.cookie('scroll_y_<?php echo $offerid ?>');
        if( x != null ) $('.funkcija3-<?php echo $offerid ?>').scrollLeft(x);
        if( y != null ) $('.funkcija3-<?php echo $offerid ?>').scrollTop(y);
    });
</script>
```

But this is only working when i refresh the page manually not when ajax refreshs the page . How can i save cookie before ajax call ? Note that i have variable offerid in funkcija.php so i cant save cookie in index.php i guess.

Comment: Keep in mind the asynchronous nature of AJAX and the fact that your current page would have no knowledge of a cookie set in another page until it is refreshed. I see no call for a page refresh.

Comment: You might be able to set the cookies in the `callMe()` function before that ajax... but what does `$offerid` contain?  If its needed for the cookie, you need to set the cookies inside the ajax success.

Comment: @JayBlanchard i also tryed to put ajax async: false but it was the same .Do u have any idea how to do it ?

Comment: @Adam Konieska it contains name of the div . Divs are created in forach loop so each div has own name depends on unique offerID .

Comment: @ToniD I must be missing something here.  Why is the ajax request necessary?  If you have the name of the div already available to you, why not just set the cookie?

Comment: @Adam Konieska I am probably doing something wrong . Div-s inside funkcija.php have overflow:scroll; . But every 30 sec when ajax call callMe() function scroll is reseted. So i want to somehow save position of scroll in cookie and restore it back after. I tryed this but its not working, it is only working when i manually refresh the page .

Comment: @ToniD why does the ajax call reset the scrollbar positions?  Can you update the question to include the HTML for the scrolling `div` tags?